# How are ``getfield`` instructions resolved?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, instruction-set, bytecode-manipulation

Alright so I have an instance of `Foo` that has an Object field `obj`, say, and a bunch of other fields.

I now create a class `Bar` and give it all the fields that `Foo` has and a few extra. In particular, `Bar` has `obj` as well.

I instrument my classes to make use of `Bar` instead of `Foo` and let them detect when they have been handed an instance of `Foo` and make them turn it into an instance of `Bar` (as in create a new instance with the information of the old).

A quick check confirms that the new instance of `Bar` has a non-null member `obj`.

So far, so good.

I now call a method that used to use `Foo` and now uses `Bar`. Another check confirms that we are indeed using the bytecode of the `Bar` version, not the old one.

Looking at the bytecode, we see that

```
getfield    Field Foo.obj:"Ljava/lang/Object;";
```

has been changed to

```
getfield    Field Bar.obj:"Ljava/lang/Object;";
```

And yet that `getfield` is returning `null`. (Or is *mostly* returning `null`, in some rare cases, it will return another object stored in some other field or it might in even rarer cases segfault.)

To me, that looks like an offset calculation gone awry.

If so, I should be able to bypass the issue by replacing the `getfield` with an `Unsafe.getObject` that uses the correct offset.

But before that, I should like to confirm that that's even possible.
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) states that

> the field is identified by field reference in the constant pool

fine, but that doesn't tell me what happens after identification.

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.getfield) specifies

> The run-time constant pool item at that index must be a symbolic reference to a field (§5.1), which gives the name and descriptor of the field as well as a symbolic reference to the class in which the field is to be found.

then

> The referenced field is resolved (§5.4.3.2). The value of the referenced field in objectref is fetched

But even [that paragraph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.2) simply says

> The declared field is the result of the field lookup.

How does that "fetching" actually happen?

Comment: You are assuming a relationship that isn’t there. The old code might have had a `getfield` instruction or not, the target field of the old instruction might have had the same name as the new field, that all is entirely irrelevant to the JVM. The JVM is not a human trying to see similar patterns somewhere. To the JVM, there is no relationship between the old code and the new code. If you read `null`, the most likely reason is that the field’s value ***is*** `null`, if it crashes the process, it’s likely caused by how your instrumentation code is messing around with it.

Comment: @Holger but if I pass that same object to an auxiliary method (just before or just after the getfield)  that checks for all fields whether they are null (by reflection) and print either "null" or class and identity hash code of the stored object, that field is not null?

Comment: Too little information. How can your code deal with instances of `Foo` and `Bar` at the same time? How do you deal with still ongoing executions of old code? …

Comment: @Holger a simple cast for checks. Either it succeeds or else I'll have to create a new instance. And because I'm dealing with a software transactional system, ongoing executions are quite simply aborted (and restated).

Comment: If your Java app segfaults, it probably means that instrumentation works wrong. Make sure instrumented classes pass verification by adding `-Xverify:all`

Comment: Please post your code. Otherwise, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: @User1291 “a simple cast for checks” implies that the possibility to be either, `Foo` or `Bar` must be there in the first place. What about method signatures and fields (which can’t be changed by Instrumentation)? Is the code consistently using a common base type of `Foo` and `Bar`, even before the Instrumentation?

Comment: @Holger eventually, they do have a common abstract ancestor, but what actually happens is that if the cast fails, we jump to a handler that knows about all relevant classes and how to handle them. We don't know whether Bar will exist or what shape it will have if it does. That decision is made with information gathered at runtime, at which point we first reinstrument the handlers before letting the rest of the classes know about them.

Comment: I wasn’t talking about what happens at or after the cast, I’m talking about what happens ***before*** reaching the cast. The code path before the `checkcast` instruction is expected to work, despite the fact that the object references may point to entirely different objects. How?

Comment: @Holger sorry, I misunderstood. There isn't a *single* ``checkcast``. **Every** access to an object we know may end up being exchanged is checked and to the rest of the code, it doesn't matter.

Comment: As already said, there is more than code. There are fields and method signatures having formal declarations which can not changed at runtime. If all of them are only referring to base classes, if every access will delegate to a handler anyway…why do you need instrumentation? You could replace the factories and handlers with doing any bytecode Instrumentation with such a code.

Comment: @Holger now you're misunderstanding. Or maybe I just suck at explaining. Every access is ``checkcast``. The handlers only come into play should the cast fail. There's no delegation otherwise.